# Java SSL sockets and ordinary sockets

Tags: java, sockets

Why in java to create SSL sockets you have to use  factories and when it comes to  ordinary sockets you use constructors? I couldn't find much on web about it any links would be amazing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because SSLSocket is an abstract class where Socket isn't. It's a design decision that allows different SSLSocket providers to exist.